# How to get SharePoint file creator name using AllDocs table?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

How can I get following information about a SharePoint document.

- Created By
- Last modified by

I am using alldocs table of sharepoint content database but can't find it very helpful.

Comment: The title of your question doesn't match the body at all? Are you trying to get the information via the SharePoint API or the database?

Comment: Sorry, I initially wanted it using object model and then edited the question later because i needed it using alldocs table. Did not remember to edit title as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are touching the alldocs table, you aren't using the object model. Further it isn't supported and is generally a bad idea. Here is some sample code to get that same information using the object model:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://your.sharepoint.server/"))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPList list = web.Lists["Documents"];
        SPListItem item = list.Items[0];
        string author = (string)item["Author"];
        DateTime modified = (DateTime)item["Modified"];
    }
}
```