# Getting Task Modified By

Tags: sharepoint, task

I'm trying to retrieve a name of the persdon who completed a task. In my Tasks list i can see 'Modified By' which is Editor.
In Sharepoint Manager I can see the persons name in the Editor column.

How can I get this value in the code

I create a task and after the `ontaskchanged` I have a code block. I've tried many permutations but cannot retrieve this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void UpdateCreatedByAndModifiedByFieldData(string strSiteUrl, string strListName, string strUserFieldName)
{
  try
  {
    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
    {
      using (SPSite site = new SPSite(strSiteUrl))
      {
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
        {
          SPList list = web.Lists[strListName];

          foreach (SPListItem listItem in list.Items)
          {
            //Read user id from a list column of user type and create SPUser object
            SPUser user = web.EnsureUser(listItem[strUserFieldName].ToString().Trim());

            if (user != null)
            {
              string userValue = user.ID + ";#" + user.Name;

              //Assign the above user to the "Created By" column
              listItem["Author"] = userValue;

              //Assign the above user to the "Modified By" column
              listItem["Editor"] = userValue;

              //Call the update method to apply the above changes
              listItem.Update();
              web.Update();
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    throw ex;
  }
}
```

Check this also

[How to get SharePoint file creator name using AllDocs table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246045/how-to-get-sharepoint-file-creator-name-using-alldocs-table)